# Enabling ns-3 logging under Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ns-3

There is a link available on how to configure Eclipse with waf to run ndnSIM programs. 
https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/HOWTO_configure_Eclipse_with_ns-3

However, I did not understand how to specify the module names so that it also print all the INFO/DEBUG/ERR/WRN logs. Right now, I am NOT able to see any logs when run from Eclipse.

An equivalent command command line for the program to run from command line is below.
NS_LOG=ndn.Consumer:ndn.Producer ./waf --run=ndn-grid-topo-plugin

I also tried to export the NS_LOG variable in Eclipse's debug/run configuration settings, with value "ndn.Consumer:ndn.Producer" but it did not work.

Can someone please tell how to achieve same in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I think this screenshot sums up the steps pretty well. Then you can probably select which module to run using the UI.

[image]